# Inserting value into excel via asp.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, insert

I have a spreadsheet that need to accept data from a asp.net app.

I have wrote some c# that allows me to read data from another spread sheet but now i want to input some data from text boxes.

```
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        string path = Server.MapPath("LOG_TEST.xlsx");
        String connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;'";
        conn.ConnectionString = connString;
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] ([NAME], [MOBILE], [EMAIL]) VALUES('" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "')",conn);
        OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Just imple insert 3 values into the spread sheet.

error im getting is below.

[image]

I believe the issue is around

```
OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

but not sure what to replace it with.

Comment: First search on google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922325/how-to-insert-a-new-row-in-excel-using-oledb-c-net

Comment: doesn't solve my issue. cheers though.

Comment: use ExecudeNonQuery rather than ExecuteReader

Comment: also looked at the permissions in the spreadsheet and all looks fine.

Comment: Still getting the same error message when using ExecuteNonQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend simplifying it just as I did it below: 
Use a spreadsheet from your Local Drive, C:, update the rest of the directory in the `connString`. Use string values in your INSERT QUERY, you can update it later. We just want to be sure that it works first! I didn't test this code btw, but I think it should work.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "C:\\SPECIFY HERE\\LOG_TEST.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=False;HDR=Yes;\"";

 string query ="INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (NAME, Mobile, Emails) VALUES ('Bob', '1', 'Whatever@mail')";

 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString);
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);

 con.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


}
```

I assume you can write a function to open your excel file something like

```
//Make sure you add these two references. 
using Microsoft.Office.Interop
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

//Call this before your insert
static void FileOpen() {
    string path = "Path.xlsx"
    var excel = new Excel.Application
    excel.Visible=True

    Excel.Workbooks books = excel.Workbooks;
    Excel.Workbook sheet = books.Open(path);
}
```

Comment: Only issue i can see is that the spreadsheet has to be open in order for it to insert the row.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with Excel files for several years now, and the easiest and most reliable way for me has been using NPOI for .NET.  It's available as a free NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/

Sample:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb1 = null;
using (var file = new FileStream("D:\\banding.xlsx", FileMode.Open, 
FileAccess.ReadWrite)) 
{
  wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
}

wb1.GetSheetAt(0).GetRow(0).GetCell(0).SetCellValue("Sample");

using (var file2 = new FileStream("D:\\banding2.xlsx", FileMode.Create, 
       FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
         wb1.Write(file2);
         file2.Close();
      }
```

Taken from Muthukrishnan Ramasamy's answer on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1c5e191-135b-45c0-9f88-cc3e02849257/npoi-how-to-write-to-an-xlsx-excel-file?forum=csharpgeneral